# Can we place bounds on the minimum trace fidelity of concatenated quantum channels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Say we have two quantum channels $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ with channel fidelities $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$. Can we place any bounds on the fidelity of the channel $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}_1\circ \mathcal{E}_2$ (let's call the fidelity of this channel $\mathcal{F}$)? Is it possible to show something like $\mathcal{F}\geq \mathcal{F}_1\mathcal{F}_2$ for a general case?

I define channel fidelity as:
$\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{E})=\textrm{min}_\rho~Tr(\rho,\mathcal{E}(\rho)),$
similar to the definition in Nielsen and Chuang.

Comment: What do you call "minimum fidelity"?

Comment: The definition of channel fidelity is given by $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{E})=\textrm{min}_{\rho}Tr(\rho,\mathcal{E}(\rho))$ (from Nielsen and Chuang). I am calling this minimum fidelity but I guess the better name is channel fidelity.

Comment: Can you include that definition in the question?

Comment: If you use the trace distance instead it is easy to see that there is a relation (triangle inequality). In turn, you can relate the trace distance to the fidelity. Not sure the resulting inequality is tight, though.